# i want to get sum of all products per day of specific moth

Tags: mysql

I want to get sum of products per day wise for one specific month

```
SELECT SUM(instock) as 'Opening Stock',SUM(receipt)as 'Receipt',date FROM product WHERE date=(SELECT Date FROM product GROUP BY date)
```

Input

```
id  instock  receipt   date
1    100      100      2019-07-01
2    300      100      2019-07-01
3    450      300      2019-07-01
1    200      100      2019-07-02
2    500      200      2019-07-02
3    300      200      2019-07-02
1    100       50      2019-07-03
2    150       50      2019-07-03
3    250       150     2019-07-03
```

Required Output

```
Opening Stock      Receipt      date 
850                500          2019-07-01
1000               500          2019-07-02
500                250          2019-07-03
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(instock) AS `Opening Stock`,
    SUM(receipt) AS Receipt,
    date
FROM product
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date;
```

In your current attempt, it appears that you were trying to use a `WHERE` clause with a subquery to limit the possible date values to only one distinct value per group.  But, `GROUP BY` does this heavy lifting for you.